# How to label raster values in plot?

Tags: r, r-raster

How could I add pixel values to the plot? I can get the values by using `click()` but I want it to appear in the plot.

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(nrow=3, ncol=3)
r[] <- 1:ncell(r)
plot(r)
click(r)
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following, which is based on pieces cobbled together from the function returned by 
`getMethod("click", signature="Raster")`.

```
myClick <- function(x, n = Inf, id = FALSE, xy = FALSE, cell = FALSE, 
                    type = "n", show = TRUE, ...) {
    i <- 0
    n <- max(n, 1)
    while (i < n) {
        i <- i + 1
        loc <- locator(1, type, ...)
        xyCoords <- cbind(x = loc$x, y = loc$y)
        cells <- na.omit(cellFromXY(x, xyCoords))
        if (length(cells) == 0)
              break
        value <- extract(x, cells)
        text(xyCoords, labels = value)
    }
}

## Try it out
myClick(r, n=4)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Josh O'Brien. It works perfectly. Just wondering how to reduce the decimal points if I were to use a true dataset. For example:
r <- raster(nrow=3, ncol=3)
r[] <- runif(ncell(r))
r
plot(r)
#continue with your myClick will give me values up to 15 decimal points. Would also appreciate if anyone could help me to plot the value on top of the pixel without using click.

Comment: To change the number of digits after the decimal, you'll need to do something like `round()` the values passed to the `text()` command. So, for instance, try `text(xyCoords, labels = round(value, 2))` to print values with just two digits after the decimal. As for your second question, it's too vaguely stated to answer here. The main bit you'll need to specify is how you intend to identify cells. After that, it shouldn't be too hard to find the coordinates at which you want to print labels, and then feed those coordinates to `text()`. If you get stuck, you can always post a new question.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to show all values you can use the `text` method:

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(nrow=3, ncol=3, vals=1:9)
plot(r)
text(r)
```

For a subset, you can do something like:

```
z <- rasterToPoints(r, function(x) x > 6 )
plot(r)
text(z[,1], z[,2], z[,3])
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is already marked as answered, but building on Josh's solution and Eddie's follow-up question, here is a little for-loop that does what Eddie was asking for (plot raster values without decimal numbers and without using `click`):

```
r <- raster(nrow=3, ncol=3)
r[] <- runif(ncell(r))

plot(r)

for(i in 1:ncell(r)){
 xycoords <- xyFromCell(r, cell = i)
 value <- extract(r, xycoords)
 text(xycoords, labels = round(value))
}
```